# How to evaluate the index of the last datetime.date in a list surpassed by a comparison date?

Tags: python, datetime

I have `datetime.date` objects stored in a list and would like to get the index of the last datetime.date before a comparison `datetime.date` stored in a variable. In the example below, the last `datetime.date` object surpassed by the comparison date would be `datetime.date(2022, 2, 1)` with an index of 2.

I have working code but it seems quite convoluted. I use a function (taken from [here](https://thispointer.com/python-how-to-find-all-indexes-of-an-item-in-a-list/)) to get a list of the index numbers of all dates occuring before the comparison date, then getting the value of the last index in this list. A simpler approach would be most welcome.

```py
import datetime

def get_index(list_of_elems, condition):
    index_pos_list = []
    for i in range(len(list_of_elems)):
        if condition(list_of_elems[i]) == True:
            index_pos_list.append(i)
    return index_pos_list

dates = [datetime.date(2020, 2, 1),
         datetime.date(2021, 2, 1),
         datetime.date(2022, 2, 1),
         datetime.date(2023, 2, 1),
         datetime.date(2024, 2, 1),
         datetime.date(2025, 2, 1)]

comparison_date = datetime.date(2022, 11, 5)

index_pos_list = get_index(dates, lambda x : x < comparison_date)

last_index = len(index_pos_list) - 1
    
print(last_index)
```

Comment: To clarify, by "last date" in the list, do you mean the last index of the last date before comp date, or the *latest* date before the comp date?

Comment: Note also, that your code only works by a fluke. For example, if you change the first date's year to 2025, it will return the index as 1, which is incorrect -- the reason is because it's not actually checking the returned list, rather using the length of the returned list (which is completely different).

Comment: @rv.kvetch Apologies if I was not clear. I would like to get the index of the last date before the comparison date. I will try to clarify in the OP. Edit: You are right about my code - thanks for notifying me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only need to get the *last index* of a date before the comparison date, I'd suggest creating a separate function `get_last_index` which does exactly that.

Also, in this case it's better to iterate over the list in reverse order, so that we can just return the first encountered index where the condition matches as true.

```py
def get_last_index(list_of_elems, condition) -> int:
    for i in range(len(list_of_elems) -1, -1, -1):
        if condition(list_of_elems[i]):
            return i
    # no date earlier than comparison date is found
    return -1

last_index = get_last_index(dates, lambda x: x < comparison_date)

print(last_index)
```

Result:

```
2
```

---

Note that the function could also be rewritten to use a generator expression, with `next` to get the first result of the expression:

```py
def get_last_index(list_of_elems, condition, default_idx=-1) -> int:
    try:
        return next(i for i in range(len(list_of_elems) - 1, -1, -1)
                    if condition(list_of_elems[i]))
    except StopIteration:  # no date earlier than comparison date is found
        return default_idx
```

Answer (score 1):

You could combine two of the lines and then you need to sort the list so that your output is correct:

```
import datetime

def get_index(list_of_elems, condition):
    index_pos_list = []
    list = list_of_elems.sort()   ####### sort
    for i in range(len(list_of_elems)):
        if condition(list_of_elems[i]) == True:
            print(list_of_elems[i])
            index_pos_list.append(i)
    return index_pos_list

dates = [datetime.date(2020, 2, 1),
     datetime.date(2021, 2, 1),
     datetime.date(2022, 2, 1),
     datetime.date(2023, 2, 1),
     datetime.date(2024, 2, 1),
     datetime.date(2025, 2, 1)]

comparison_date = datetime.date(2022, 11, 5)

index_pos_list = len(get_index(dates, lambda x : x < comparison_date)) - 1   #####  combined lines

print(index_pos_list)
```